# Different results when pulling docker image from registry

Tags: tomcat, docker, dockerfile, war

here is my case:

I'm building an app's Dockerfile on top of an existing custom tomcat Dockerfile. I'm adding my warfile to my app's Dockerfile, building it and everything is perfect. I create my container in my computer, explore it and I find my warfile there.

After that, I'm tagging my file and uploading it to my aws registry container. **Then I proceed to pull that image in my QA server** and when I create my new container I can't find my War file, **I can only find the default ROOT.war** file there.

Exploring the docker history I can find this (Both, QA server and my laptop):

```
**IMAGE        |       CREATED      |       CREATED BY  |  SIZE |        COMMENT**

501d00ca77c3   |     45 minutes ago |     /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["catalina.sh" "run"]     0 B

4cf854413820   |     45 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 8080/tcp               0 B

bbfa93183732   |     45 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:505585dd0d5d380e9   42.56 MB

4ccbbbbba28a   |     45 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps &   0 B

fc6eef024043   |     2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["catalina.sh" "run"]     0 B

missing        |     2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 8080/tcp               0 B

missing        |     2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update -y && apt-get insta   124.2 MB
```

The layer containing the warfile is supossed to be there:

**bbfa93183732   |     45 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:505585dd0d5d380e9   42.56 MB**

**This is my Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mySuperSecretAwesomeId.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/tomcat:1.0

RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps && mkdir /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

ADD ./webapps/ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

*Does anyone has a clue?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're saying the copy is in the history on both your dev and qa system? If so, then it sounds like you didn't run a container with this new image, what command are you using to attempt to do that?

Comment: I'm creating the container with the new image. My image did not exist in my QA server.

I'm using the following command when exploring my container


**docker run -it mySuperSecretAwesomeId.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/dh:1.0 /bin/bash**

Comment: Do you mean you were tagging your image? Can you add those steps you performed (+output)

Comment: *After building my app's Dockerfile I'm getting*

   **501d00ca77c3 id on dh:1.0**

then

    **docker tag 501d00ca77c3 mySuperSecretAwesomeId.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/dh:1.0**


after that on my QA 
   **docker pull docker tag 501d00ca77c3 mySuperSecretAwesomeId.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/dh:1.0**

My hash code matches with the hash code presented on my registry

Comment: @lorenzvth7

I even deleted my app's local image and pulled it from the registry, and the war file was there, but still not in my QA server